# Django ModelForm update don't work

Tags: django, transactions, django-forms

Hi I have problem with ModelForms. When I'm trying update object form two classes using transaction nothing happening.

My form class:

```
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    employers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employer.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = '__all__'
```

My model classes:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Team', max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    team_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project_menager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    hourly_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    working_time = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

and finally my  view:

```
def TeamUpdateView(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        team_form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if team_form.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                team = Team.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(name=str(team_form['name'].value()))
                for e in team_form['employers'].value():
                    Employer.objects.filter(pk=e).update(team=team)
            print(team_form.errors)
            return redirect('resources:ResourcesListView')
    else:
        team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=pk)
        team_form = TeamForm(initial={'name': team.name})  # milestone_form = MilestoneForm()
        context = {'team_form': team_form, 'form_pk': pk}  # , 'milestone
        return render(request, 'resources/resources_edit_modal.html', context)
```

When i print form error i can see somethings like this:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>Team with this Name already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some formatting issues - I'm guessing that's just when posting on SO?

Comment: Yest only when i trying to send post request